# CSS FlexBox cropping content with min- sizes

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to get "FlexBox" columns to stretch and squish to fill horizontal space, but with horizontal scrolling at small sizes so as not to crop their content.

What I've done is create a container element with an layout out the flexbox direction, orientation, etc. that has an overflow of auto:

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    overflow:auto;
}
```

I have a column:

```
.column {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

And content in the column:

```
.column-content {
    min-width:200px;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="column">
        <div class="column-content">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="column-content">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="column-content">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="column-content">...</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

When you scale the viewport down horizontally, the columns will shrink all the way down to 100px, their min-width. But what I want them to do is not shrink beyond 200px, their content's min-width.

I can't set the columns min-width higher because I don't know what the content of these columns is going to look like, and what their minimum width will be as different components are going to be loaded in there.

Here's a plunk illustrating:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CoIYdHXQVnAYzSp5m1tG?p=preview

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Flexbox here?

Comment: Just playing with flexboxes. But is there another way to do this; - columns grow to fill container, - don't crop their contents horizontally but fill height and scroll vertically, - container scrolls overflow, - with an unspecified number of columns??

Answer (score 0):

The table display properties are better suited for this task (and have better browser support):

http://cssdeck.com/labs/0jrgaysm

```
.container {
  display: table;
}

.column {
  overflow:hidden;
  min-width:100px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.column-content {
  min-width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Someone can confirm if it's right? Tables is really better suited than flexbox?